# Does null inherit from Object as well in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Does null inherit from Object as well in C#?

Where does the null itself defined?

Comment: Some people find downvoting to be a joyous task. I think this is a very good question. +1

Comment: Thanks, I know what you mean.

Comment: Yes, this is a good question.  Why anyone would downvote this is beyond me, +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

null is of the "null type", which does inherit from object.

See ECMA-334 11.2.7

Comment: Per your suggestion I'm reading http://en.csharp-online.net/ECMA-334:_11.2_Reference_types While I would agree the "null type" is a Reference type, I'm not sure if it inherits from object.

Comment: 11.2.2 says "Every type in C# directly or indirectly derives from the object class type."
In the CLR itself, things are a little more complicated (System.TypedReference will report that it inherits from object, but cannot be cast to object) but in 'pure' C#, every type inherits from object.

Answer (score 10):

> Does null inherit from Object as well in C#?

Unlike in some other systems, `null` is not defined in terms of a class or an instance. On the contrary, it signifies the *absence* of any instance, and it doesn't have a type. It is implicitly converted to whatever reference type fits the context. The widest conversion (i.e. when no other can be inferred) is to `object`. But still, `null` is not generally of type `object`.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what you're saying by "...it [null] doesn't have a type... it is implicitly converted to whatever type fits the context... [it] is not generally of type object."

Comment: Chris, well, you could hypothetically think that `null` is actually a hard-coded constant of type `object` that just gets converted implicitly to other types depending on context. This is not the case.

Comment: Some people seem to take issue with my explanation. Please leave a comment saying what you object to!

Answer (score 6):

`null` is not an object - it is a language keyword that denotes the lack of an object reference.

Comment: That's they key--it's a *language keyword*, and it denotes the absence of an *object reference*.

Comment: Or a Nullable<T> value without a value (HasValue==false)

Answer (score 3):

> Where does the null itself defined?

[null](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edakx9da.aspx) is a keyword.  null is not a type.

There are two kinds of variables, each with its own set of nullability rules.

### Reference type variables

The variable is typed and can refer to instances of the same or different types.

```
//The reference type is System.Object and
//  the instance type is System.String
object s = "123";
```

With reference type variables, null indicates an absence of an instance.

```
//The reference type is System.Object and
//  there is no instance.
object x = null;
```

Using a reference type variable that has no instance will result in a null reference exception.

```
string s = null;
s = s + "a"; //BOOM.
```

### Value type variables

Value type variables have a single type, and the values assigned must be of this type and no other.

```
int i = 3;
```

With certain value type variables (only those that are of the type `Nullable<T>`), null may be assigned.  This indicates the absence of value.

```
int? i = null;
```

Using a value type that has no value does not generate null reference exceptions - there is no *reference* involved.

```
int? i = null
if (i < 3) //false
```

Answer (score 1):

I think null is not an object per se.

Answer (score 0):

null is not a type, it is a value.  More specifically it is a value that is by definition the abscence of a value.  In C# null is convertible to any reference type.

So null does not inherit from System.Object but it is a value convertible to any object which does not inherit from System.ValueType.

Comment: Don't forget the *other* use of the null keyword with Nullable<T> - to which it isn't exactly *convertible* - rather the compiler uses .HasValue etc as an alternative.

Comment: @Marc, I intentionally limited it to referenc types to avoid issues with Nullable ;)